# Windows 10 User no Longer Requires Password

Tags: windows-10, security

My `Windows 10` desktop has always required a password; recently that changed and the desktop boots straight to desktop. I am the only user of this system however I like having that prompt. I have made only hardware changes recently; I removed to hard drives, but not the main drive with the OS on it. A cursory look online only reflects how to make this change and not a use case as I am describing; this includes:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/how-to-disable-password-prompt-on-startup-in/4879c0e6-43e6-4a12-9ca3-e7fc91e20a31

Any help or feedback is appreciated; as I said above I have made no changes to the OS or more specifically to the accounts on the OS.

Comment: Did you add / enable Windows Hello?

Comment: I do not believe so; I am not familiar with that but doing a little digging, under `Sign-in options`, I see several `Window Hello` references, all of which are listed as unavailable so I presume nothing has changed there.

Comment: Check out Windows Hello carefully as that is the only secure way that a Password or PIN would not be required.

Comment: Please check if **Require Sign-in** was set as **When PC wakes up from sleep**. **Setting**-> **Sign-in options**-> **Require Sign-in**.  Or you could try to set password for the specific user in **Local Users and Groups** to see if the issue can be resolved.